# Lego Dimensions GhostBusters 2016 28/29

Tags: wii-u, lego-dimensions

My Lego Dimensions shows that I need 29 gold bricks. However, this guide says that there should only be 28.

http://www.brickstolife.com/all-guide-list/ghostbusters-adventure-world-guide-2016/

Any clue why my Wii-U version would say that I need 29? I checked through this guide and I certainly have the required gold bricks.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the DLC already. Not sure what else to do. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After patch 2.1.0 came out this was resolved